Find the total area of two triangles within a square
I solved this but others have conflicting answers, I'd love some validation:

Total area of the green triangles.


Please show your work on how to solve this - lots of Pythagoras and more needed.
Ok, more info based on comments. I annotated the image with letters so I can explain my logic. Check the second image for that detail.

First,both triangles are right. This is provable by the slopes of the lines eh and fg, they're the inverse of each other. If the lower left corner (point c) is origin,
eh can be represented as y = 1/3x +1, and
fg by y = -3x+12.
This also means the intersection coordinate (point o) is x= 33/10, y= 21/10.
Since they're right triangles, areas are
for A =  of * oe/2
for B =  og * oh/2
We start by calculating oh. Since we know oi (21/10 from above), and ih (4 - 33/10), we use Pythagoras to find oh = sqrt (49/10) = ~2.2136
now oe is easy because we know eh is sqrt 40, so oe = eh-oh= ~4.11096
now for og, since we know hg = sqrt 13, and oh = sqrt (49/10), use Pythagoras to get og = 2.4846
Since fg = sqrt 40, of = fg-og = 3.4785
Plug them in, A = 7.15, B = 3.15, total green area = 10.3
Anything wrong here?

What are your thoughts?  If you solved it, what is your solution?

Welcome to Math.SE! ... "I solved this but others have conflicting answers" Please include the work you did, and if possible the work done by the others. It may be easier for someone to confirm your logic (or spot an error) than to work through the problem from scratch. Besides, showing your own work informs readers about your skill level, and helps them avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand. (Add an additional info to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) ... Good luck!

The picture suggests that these two green triangles are right triangles resulting from a perpendicular intersection.  Is that stated in the original source of this problem?

To @hardmath - yes, that's provably correct, the 2 green shapes are right triangles

"The picture suggests that these two green triangles are right triangles"  You can't assume that! (even though they are.)  you have to have a reason.

Edited the post based on suggestions here. Added my solution, how I got there and a detailed image that helps to follow my logic.

We can calculate the coordinates of O based on intersecting those two lines, with the formula for $EH$ being $y = -3x + 12$, and $FG$ by $y = \frac{1}{3}x + 1$ (P/S you got them swapped in the post!). This means they are indeed perpendicular, which means $\Delta EOF$ and $\Delta GOH$ are right triangles. (Notice this fact, we will use them later).
The coordinates of $O$ being $\left(\frac{33}{10}, \frac{21}{10}\right)$ is correct though.
In the post, you use the formula $OE = EH - OH$, while true isn't recommended since it can lead to inaccuracies. Instead, I recommend calculating it directly, along with $OF, OH, OG$ by the formula
$$
\text{length between A and B} = \sqrt{(x_A - x_B)^2 + (y_A - y_B)^2}
$$
since the formula gives us the exact form of their lengths. We have, respectively:
$$
OE = \sqrt{\left(\frac{33}{10} - 2\right)^2 + \left(\frac{21}{10} - 6\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{169}{10}} = \frac{13}{\sqrt{10}} \\
OF = \sqrt{\left(\frac{33}{10} - 0\right)^2 + \left(\frac{21}{10} - 1\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{121}{10}} = \frac{11}{\sqrt{10}} \\
OH = \sqrt{\left(\frac{33}{10} - 0\right)^2 + \left(\frac{21}{10} - 1\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{49}{10}} = \frac{7}{\sqrt{10}} \\
OG = \sqrt{\left(\frac{33}{10} - 6\right)^2 + \left(\frac{21}{10} - 3\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{81}{10}} = \frac{9}{\sqrt{10}}
$$
Beforehand I mentioned that EOF and GOH are right triangles, and therefore their areas are $$\text{Area}(\Delta EOF) = \frac{OE \cdot OF}{2} = \frac{\frac{13}{\sqrt{10}} \cdot \frac{11}{\sqrt{10}}}{2} = \frac{143}{20}\\ \text{Area}(\Delta GOH) = \frac{OH \cdot OG}{2} = \frac{\frac{7}{\sqrt{10}} \cdot \frac{9}{\sqrt{10}}}{2} = \frac{63}{20}$$
and therefore $$\text{Area}(\text{Green region}) = \text{Area}(\Delta EOF) + \text{Area}(\Delta GOH) = \frac{143}{20} + \frac{63}{20} = \frac{103}{10} = 10.3$$
So yes, your post is overall correct, just a few things I noticed you can do (and the $EH$ and $FG$ being swapped thing).

thank you and oops on accidentally swapping the line equations!


Another approach: In figure F'H is the reflection of FH on DH.
$S_{ACDH}=\frac 12 S_{ACEG}=\frac{6\times6}2=18$
$S_{ABH}=\frac  {1\times 4}2=2$
$S_{BCD}=\frac{5\times 2}2=5$
$\Rightarrow S_{BDH}=18-(5+2)= 11$
$BH=\sqrt{4^2+1^2}=\sqrt{17}=4.12$
$F'H=FH=\sqrt{3^2+2^2}=\sqrt {13}$
$HM=BH-BN=\sqrt{17}-0.53\approx 3.59$
$FM=\sqrt{FH^2-HM^2}=\sqrt{13-3.59^2}= 0.34$
$S_{FBH}=\frac{FM\times BH}2=\frac {0.34\times 4.12}2=0.7$
Finally:
$S=11-0.7=10.3$

This approach by synthetic geometry confirms your answer of $10.3$ for total area.
Since $DH=BG=2$, then $GH$ passes through the center $O$ of square $ABCD$. Through $O$ draw $KL\perp GH$, and join $KH$, $HL$, $LG$, $GK$. Since by symmetry $KA=LC=2$, then $KHLG$ is a square, with diagonals $KL=GH$. Since $FK=2-1=EL=3-2=1$, then $FKLE$ is a parallelogram, and $FE=KL=GH$. And since by Pythagoras $KH=\sqrt {20}$, then $KO=OH=\sqrt{10}$.
Now draw $HM, ON\parallel DA$. Since $\triangle HMG\sim \triangle OJN$, then $OJ=3NJ$. And since $ON=1$, then$$OJ=\frac{6}{2\sqrt {10}}\approx .95$$and$$NJ=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{10}}\approx .32$$
Thus in area$$\triangle FJH=\frac{1}{2}FJ\cdot JH=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{10}+.32\right)\left(\sqrt{10}+.95\right)\approx 7.16$$and$$\triangle EJG=\frac{1}{2}(EJ\cdot JG)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{10}-.32\right)\left(\sqrt{10}-.95\right)\approx 3.14$$and$$\triangle FJH+\triangle EJG\approx 7.16+3.14=10.30$$
